# I get an error when running qemu-systems-x86_64

Tags: qemu

when i run qemu-system-x86_64(version 6.2.0) in ubuntu22.04(wsl2), i get an error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment 
  parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_ShmPutImage)
  Segment id in failed request:  0x600013
  Serial number of failed request:  269
  Current serial number in output stream:  270
```

i searched it in google, but there is almost no answer about this question.
but when i run qemu-system-riscv in shell, it's ok. i get a TUI.

Comment: Welcome! As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Comment: I found that it can run successfully on Ubuntu20.04(wsl)